# Trying to install Keras with Python 3.8 and it keeps finding the wrong CUDA version (even though 11.0 is not installed on my PC)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

So I'm doing a project for my master and I need to install Keras. I'd like to work in Pycharm, so I'm trying to install it through there (although I have also tried it through Anaconda) and I keep getting the error message included at the end.

I have a GTX970 installed and am running Windows 10, I have CUDA 10.1 installed (which should work with Keras). When I first tried, I did not have 11.0 installed, but the error was the same. At some point I decided to try it with 11.0 installed, still the same error. Now I have removed CUDA 11.0 again (everything CUDA 11.0 related I could find through programs and even removed the remaining empty CUDA 11.0 folder). I had one attempt where this line was not present in the error, but I don't know how or why this happened:
`- feature:|@/win-64::__cuda==11.0=0`

Does anyone know what I should do here? If more information is needed, I'm happy to add it

````
If python is on the left-most side of the chain, that's the version you've asked for.
When python appears to the right, that indicates that the thing on the left is somehow
not available for the python version you are constrained to. Note that conda will not
change your python version to a different minor version unless you explicitly specify
that.

The following specifications were found to be incompatible with your CUDA driver:

  - feature:/win-64::__cuda==11.0=0
  - feature:|@/win-64::__cuda==11.0=0

Your installed CUDA driver is: 11.0```
````

Comment: Can you tell me which tensorflow-gpu version do you have installed?

Comment: I believe the error message is not referring to your CUDA version but rather the driver for your GPU card. Go to Nvidia and search for a driver for your card that is compatible with CUDA 10.

Comment: @YannickFunk I don't have that installed, attempting to install gives the exact same error

Comment: @GerryP I would like to retain my up-to-date GPU driver, I also use this pc for gaming, so going back to old drivers can have negative results.

Comment: understand but I had a similar message about CUDA 11 and resolved it that way. Perhaps there are other solutions..

Comment: Can you try using this custom wheel: https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/windows/gpu/tensorflow_gpu-2.3.0-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl

Comment: @GerryP I ended up frustrated enough to try this. I removed al Nvidia programs from my pc, only installed the older drivers. Still didn't work, but the error changed, then I moved to an older Python version and that fixed it. Hopefully everything doesn't break when I update my drivers....

Comment: Yes I did forget to mention that I also had to change to an older python release. Glad you have it working!!